# Is it a good idea to have a business service depend upon interfaces to other business services?

Tags: c#, architecture

I am utilizing the unit of work pattern, the repository pattern, that are used in a Business Logic Layer that are typically called Services. Is it a good idea to have a business service depend upon interfaces to other business services within this type of architecture to reuse functionality?

Comment: Can you give examples of the business services you mean?

Comment: Sure. I am referring to the Business Logic Layer of the architecture. So for example a ProductService that implements IProductService that have the routines like 'AddProduct' or 'UpdateProductPrice' or 'GetProducts'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless your business services are absolutely trivial, they will almost always have to be decomposed into finer grained bits of logic.  This logic is often extracted into a "domain" layer, separate from the service layer.

Comment: I thought the BLL would have all the logic in it and the domain layer was used to build a vocabulary of classes to describe the business problem. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, that's fine

There's a caveat to be aware of, however:

When working with a [domain model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) (as opposed to a [transaction script](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/transactionScript.html) based architecture), **make sure you don't accidentally miss a business concept by organizing your business logic into just services.**

**Often, a piece of logic belongs into a business entity together with the data it is working on.** Just putting all logic into services will make your model awkward to use.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the reply. Are you open to private discussions on this? I have a few additional questions and I am not sure if I should ask them here because this question has been put on hold. Either way thanks.